# Recursive IntentService with AlarmManager

Tags: android, recursion, alarmmanager, intentservice

This is more or less a design question; but nonetheless. I have an `IntentService` that fires off a `PendingIntent` that calls itself every 15 minutes.

My question is, for the `AlarmManager`; should I be using either:

- `set(...)` or
- `setRepeating(...)`

The problem I noticed with `setRepeating(...)` is that I'll quickly get into an infinite loop, but I imagine this is because of the start time. If I use `set(...)`; it works as expected without an infinite loop; the design question is should I be using `setRepeating(...)` over just adding a `set(...)` after every alarm call? If so, how can I do that without an infinite loop while having a recursive `IntentService` that calls itself each time the alarm goes off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `set` and `setRepeating` are okay.

`set` is easier to follow. You have the control over when your `IntentService` is launched next.

I would recommend the use of `setRepeating`: why repeat yourself? For the infinite loop issue, save a `boolean` value in your `SharedPreferences` when you set the alarm. On the next launch of the `IntentService`, check the value. If its `true`, the alarm is already set. Else, this must be the first launch: set the `repeating` alarm.

You will need to implement a receiver that listens for `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. When this intent is received, set the repeating alarm WITHOUT checking the `SharedPreferences` value. But DO set this value to `true` after issuing the `setRepeating` request.